# Сверстать текст в три колонки

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, jquery

Вот макет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Текст в админке должен набираться в один столбик. Как его вывести на страницу в три столбика?

Comment: http://g.zeos.in/?q=css%20display%20text%20in%20columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам необходимо воспользоваться свойством `column-count: 3` и всё получится. 
Добавил разделение линией для наглядности (Если надо без него - убираем `column-rule:`).
Вот пример с 3 колонками.

```js
    inp.oninput= function () {
        let text = document.getElementById(`inp`).value;
        document.getElementById(`text`).innerText = text;
    }
```

```css
    .text {
        padding-bottom:20px;
        width:100%;
        text-align:justify;
        column-count: 3; /*количество колонок, на которое хотим разбить текст*/
        -moz-column-count: 3; /*для мозилы*/
        -webkit-column-count: 3; /*для webkit браузеров*/
        column-gap: 40px; /*отступ между колонками*/
        -moz-column-gap: 40px;
        -webkit-column-gap: 40px;
        column-rule: 1px solid #000; /*если требуется по дизайну, разделяем колонки линией*/
        -moz-column-rule: 1px solid #000;
        -webkit-column-rule: 1px solid #000;
    }
```

```html
<div id="PurumPumPum">
    <input id="inp">
</div>
<div class="text" id="text"></div>
```